# Nested VLOOKUPs with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

This is for newest version of Python 3

I am trying to achieve a new dataframe that is created via nested vlookups (like in Excel), but based on conditions.

Example

df1

```
Location        Item         QTY
NYC             I1            5
NYC             I2            0
PARIS           I1            0
PARIS           I2            5
```

df2

```
Place    1Closest      2Closest
P1       NYC            PARIS
P2       PARIS           NYC
```

What we want
result_df

```
Place        Item      Choice
P1            I1        NYC
P1            I2        PARIS
P2            I1        NYC
P2            I2        PARIS
```

So, essentially, it needs to look at each place, look at the 1st closest location, see the item is kept there (qty > 0 ), if it is return the location. Otherwise, go to the next location.

My idea so far:

```
#We'll take the Cartesian product of 2 prior dataframes that I whipped up to make this easier

pd1

Place
P1
P2



pd2


Item
I1
I2
```

And for code hereafter:

```
def cartesian_product(*arrays):
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrays] + [la], dtype=dtype)
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[...,i] = a
    return arr.reshape(-1, la)  


def cartesian_product_multi(*dfs):
    idx = cartesian_product(*[np.ogrid[:len(df)] for df in dfs])
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.column_stack([df.values[idx[:,i]] for i,df in enumerate(dfs)]))

result_df = cartesian_product_multi(*[pdf1,pdf2])
```

which results in

```
Place      Item
P1         I1
P1         I2
P2         I1
P2         I2
```

Now what we want is the third column, the qty. A lot of what I've read online has had to deal with merge / vlookups. But based on what I have, You would vlookup on place,return the closest location, check to see if the quantity in df1 for that location and item are >0. If so, return the location. If not, go to next closest. With that in mind, we can't merge on these 2 dfs because they don't share common indices, you'd have to merge on the result_df.

Comment: There is no I1 in Paris so why do you have `P2            I1        PARIS`?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake. Edited. Much easier to read in a matrix format than it is in columns but I think columns makes it easier to code for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
res = df2.melt(id_vars='Place', value_name='Location')

# outer join
res = res.merge(df1, on='Location', how='outer')

# create closest rank
res['rank'] = res['variable'].str.extract(r'(^\d+)').astype(int)

# sort by place and rank
res = res.sort_values(by=['Place', 'rank']).drop(['rank', 'variable'], 1)

# remove those Locations with 0 items and only keep the first Location by item
res = res[res['QTY'] > 0].drop_duplicates(subset=['Place', 'Item'], keep='first')

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Place Location Item  QTY
0    P1      NYC   I1    5
7    P1    PARIS   I2    5
5    P2    PARIS   I2    5
2    P2      NYC   I1    5
```

If only *Place*, *Location* and *Item* are needed, do:

```
res = res[['Place', 'Item', 'Location']]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  Place Item Location
0    P1   I1      NYC
7    P1   I2    PARIS
5    P2   I2    PARIS
2    P2   I1      NYC
```

Comment: I edited the request to ensure that what I'm wanting is result_df. Now if IIUC, what you're starting off with is place and item, but you're returning our desired location as well as quantity?

Comment: @bosois You could drop those columns if needed

Comment: The third line is giving me an error 'cannot float NaN to integer'. Does python treat 0's as NaN's?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I run res.replace(np.nan,0), it still gives me that same float error.

Comment: If you're reading this in the future, I had to drop out extra columns df2 and then it worked. Thanks very much, Dani!